# CORS on express js api Access-Control-Allow-Origin despite CORS enabled

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors

I'm using Express JS to serve an API on a server, I've got several routes setup, post, get, etc and all of my routes are working fine except my post route. I've enabled CORS both through the Cors package, and through some additional middleware but still getting a CORS issue, my request from example.com is going to compiler.example.com and is returning a CORS issue, my setup for my middleware is:

```js
// require packages etc...

app.use(helmet())
app.use(cors())
app.use(expressSanitizer())
app.use(express.json())

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE')
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type')
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)

  // Pass to next layer of middleware
  next()
});

// routes come next
```

My error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://compiler.example.com/api/endpoint' from origin 'http://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

VM734:1 POST https://compiler.example/api/endpoint net::ERR_FAILED
```

Not sure where I'm going wrong... only seems to be affecting my POST.

Comment: On which of the two domains does your server run?

Comment: Try to avoid http if you can

Comment: Both are running on https, on the same server, the front-end and the API, the API is running on a subdomain of the domain where the front-end is.

Comment: "*`http://example.com`*" does not appear to run on https. And are you saying that the express application whose code you've posted does serve both domains?

Comment: change the first line from * to `req.headers.origin` and pass " true" as a string

Comment: FYI: `*` is dangerous and incorrect unless you're making an API that is truly meant to be consumed by *anybody* on the Internet. You should use a real value, namely the host you expect to receive values from

Comment: How I'm implementing my API has no relation to the issue that I'm experiencing and isn't helpful to the context. Simply, I'm an experiencing an error that I shouldn't be despite enabling CORS. my description is a mocked version, and my api and front-end are both `https`.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue as you , I solved it by adding cors as app options like this :

```
app.options('*', cors());
```

As well as adding cors on my routes like this :

```
const cors = require('cors');
module.exports = (app) => {

    const notes = require('../controllers/note.controller.js');

    app.post('/notes', cors(), notes.create);

    app.get('/notes', cors(), notes.findAll);

    app.get('/notes/:noteId', cors(), notes.findOne);

    app.post('/notes/:noteId', cors(), notes.update);

    app.delete('/notes/:noteId', cors(), notes.delete);


}
```

I honestly don't why it works like this and doesn't work as the normal way specified everywhere.